# ContentDecodingError when getting text with beautiful soup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, gzip

I have a list of URLs (from HuffPost UK) I need to get text from. I store them in a csv file but I just copy/pasted them below as a list. I have two problems with my code (which used to work fine with some other publishers...).

1. It randomly stops with ContentDecodingError.
2. It randomly fails to generate text.

I say randomly because when I run it several times it stops at different URLs. Sometimes it prints text, sometimes it prints an empty string for the same URL. I have no idea what is going on. Could anyone suggest what is wrong? I'll greatly appreciate your help.

My code:

```
import codecs
import translitcodec
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_text(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")    
    # delete unwanted tags:
    for s in soup(['h2', 'figure', 'script', 'style', 'table']):
        s.decompose()
    # use separator to separate paragraphs and subtitles!
    article_soup = [s.get_text(separator="\n", strip=True) for s in soup.find_all( 'div', {'class': 'content-list-component text'})]    
    text = ' '.join(article_soup)
    text = codecs.encode(text, 'translit/one').encode('ascii', 'replace') #replace traslit with ascii
    text = u"{}".format(text) #encode to unicode
    print text
    return text

urls = ['http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/damian-green-tories-housing-education_n_17244280.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/the-waugh-zone-thursday-june-22-2017_n_17253136.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/argos-toys-christmas-2017_n_17248026.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/ore-oduba-strictly-come-dancing-joanne-clifton_n_17253186.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/joanne-clifton-flashdance-strictly-come-dancing_n_17253268.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/grenfell-tower-cladding-may-have-released-hydrogen-cyanide_n_17252776.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/uk-will-have-to-trawl-through-19000-eu-laws-to-decide-which-ones-to-keep-after-brexit_n_17242732.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/queens-speech-2017-jeremy-corbyn-theresa-may_n_17241446.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/piers-morgan-good-morning-britain-bbc-breakfast-dan-walker-ratings_n_17252222.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/worst-bridezilla-stories-ever-reddit_n_17253210.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/donald-trump-uk-state-visit-shelved-after-no-mention-in-queens-speech-2017_n_17239686.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/failure-may-state_n_17242710.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/queens-speech-2017-13-things-missing-from-theresa-mays-first-one_n_17239692.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/heartbroken-best-man-gatecrashes-bride-and-grooms-wedding-photos-and-its-comedy-gold_n_17253104.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/queens-speech-2017-jeremy-corbyn-mocks-theresa-mays-imploding-minority-government_n_17242692.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/asda-the-little-mermaid-swimsuit-topless_n_17253262.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/20/chaotic-brexit-theresa-may_n_17248024.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/the-waugh-zone-special-queens-speech-2017_n_17246444.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/grenfell-tower-residents-to-be-rehoused-in-luxury-kensington-row-flats_n_17242518.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/gin-does-not-help-relieve-hay-fever-experts-say_n_17243102.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/20/theresa-may-savoy_n_17227558.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/crewe-crane-collapse_n_17243884.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/rebecca-burger-french-fitness-blogger-killed-by-exploding-cream-dispenser_n_17253286.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/05/31/the-waugh-zone-may-31-201_0_n_16891450.html?ir=UK+Politics', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/theresa-may-reveals-tests-show-other-towers-combustible-following-grenfell-tower-fire_n_17253204.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/owen-jones-gleefully-brands-daily-mail-an-open-sewer_n_17253464.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/laura-kenny-interview-ambition-after-pregnancy_n_17252498.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/boris-johnson-radio-4-eddie-mair-two-ronnies_n_17245044.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/grenfell-tower-homes-theresa-may_n_17246764.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/dup-pushover-deal_n_17253218.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/khan-remain-rights_n_17243656.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/love-island-zara-holland-sex-miss-great-britain_n_17242768.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/man-sent-home-from-work-wearing-shorts_n_17243276.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/courteney-cox-fillers-surgery-face_n_17252410.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/jeremy-corbyn-observed-protocol-by-not-bowing-to-the-queen_n_17240658.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/alexandra-shulman-british-vogue-good-morning-britain-the-queen_n_17253200.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/teaching-excellence-framework-results-universities-gold-ranking_n_17253426.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/prince-harry-slams-decision-to-make-him-walk-behind-princess-dianas-coffin_n_17253188.html?utm_hp_ref=uk']
for url in urls:
    print url
    text = get_text(url)
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ContentDecodingError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-54bdf2585415> in <module>()
     21 for url in urls:
     22     print url
---> 23     text = get_text(url)

<ipython-input-12-54bdf2585415> in get_text(url)
      5 
      6 def get_text(url):
----> 7     r = requests.get(url)
      8     soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
      9     # delete unwanted tags:

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.pyc in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     68 
     69     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 70     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     71 
     72 

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.pyc in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     54     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     55     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 56         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     57 
     58 

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.pyc in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    486         }
    487         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 488         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    489 
    490         return resp

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.pyc in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    628 
    629         # Resolve redirects if allowed.
--> 630         history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
    631 
    632         # Shuffle things around if there's history.

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.pyc in resolve_redirects(self, resp, req, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies, **adapter_kwargs)
    188                 proxies=proxies,
    189                 allow_redirects=False,
--> 190                 **adapter_kwargs
    191             )
    192 

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.pyc in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    639 
    640         if not stream:
--> 641             r.content
    642 
    643         return r

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.pyc in content(self)
    795                 self._content = None
    796             else:
--> 797                 self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
    798 
    799         self._content_consumed = True

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.pyc in generate()
    722                     raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
    723                 except DecodeError as e:
--> 724                     raise ContentDecodingError(e)
    725                 except ReadTimeoutError as e:
    726                     raise ConnectionError(e)

ContentDecodingError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing: incorrect header check',))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this problem. I needed to use Selenium & PhantomJS before opening each url to allow the page to load properly.

This piece of code I added before creating my soup helped to solve the problem:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='PATH TO phantomjs')
driver.get(url) 
waitForLoad(driver)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

I also used the function waitForLoad(driver): described in [this O'Reilly book](http://index-of.es/Varios/Ryan%20Mitchell-Web%20Scraping%20with%20Python_%20Collecting%20Data%20from%20the%20Modern%20Web-O'Reilly%20Media%20(2015).pdf).

This is the final working code:

```
import codecs
import translitcodec
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

def waitForLoad(driver):
    elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html") 
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        if count > 20:
            print("Timing out after 10 seconds and returning")
            return
        time.sleep(.5) 
        try:
            elem == driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html") 
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return

def get_text(url):
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='PATH TO phantomjs')
    driver.get(url) 
    waitForLoad(driver)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml") 
    # delete unwanted tags:
    for s in soup(['h2', 'figure', 'script', 'style', 'table']):
        s.decompose()
    # use separator to separate paragraphs and subtitles!
    article_soup = [s.get_text(separator="\n", strip=True) for s in soup.find_all( 'div', {'class': 'content-list-component text'})]    
    text = ' '.join(article_soup)
    text = codecs.encode(text, 'translit/one').encode('ascii', 'replace') #replace traslit with ascii
    text = u"{}".format(text) #encode to unicode
    print text
    return text

urls = ['http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/damian-green-tories-housing-education_n_17244280.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/the-waugh-zone-thursday-june-22-2017_n_17253136.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/argos-toys-christmas-2017_n_17248026.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/ore-oduba-strictly-come-dancing-joanne-clifton_n_17253186.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/joanne-clifton-flashdance-strictly-come-dancing_n_17253268.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/grenfell-tower-cladding-may-have-released-hydrogen-cyanide_n_17252776.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/uk-will-have-to-trawl-through-19000-eu-laws-to-decide-which-ones-to-keep-after-brexit_n_17242732.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/queens-speech-2017-jeremy-corbyn-theresa-may_n_17241446.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/piers-morgan-good-morning-britain-bbc-breakfast-dan-walker-ratings_n_17252222.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/worst-bridezilla-stories-ever-reddit_n_17253210.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/donald-trump-uk-state-visit-shelved-after-no-mention-in-queens-speech-2017_n_17239686.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/failure-may-state_n_17242710.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/queens-speech-2017-13-things-missing-from-theresa-mays-first-one_n_17239692.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/heartbroken-best-man-gatecrashes-bride-and-grooms-wedding-photos-and-its-comedy-gold_n_17253104.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/queens-speech-2017-jeremy-corbyn-mocks-theresa-mays-imploding-minority-government_n_17242692.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/asda-the-little-mermaid-swimsuit-topless_n_17253262.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/20/chaotic-brexit-theresa-may_n_17248024.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/the-waugh-zone-special-queens-speech-2017_n_17246444.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/grenfell-tower-residents-to-be-rehoused-in-luxury-kensington-row-flats_n_17242518.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/gin-does-not-help-relieve-hay-fever-experts-say_n_17243102.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/20/theresa-may-savoy_n_17227558.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/crewe-crane-collapse_n_17243884.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/rebecca-burger-french-fitness-blogger-killed-by-exploding-cream-dispenser_n_17253286.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/05/31/the-waugh-zone-may-31-201_0_n_16891450.html?ir=UK+Politics', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/theresa-may-reveals-tests-show-other-towers-combustible-following-grenfell-tower-fire_n_17253204.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/owen-jones-gleefully-brands-daily-mail-an-open-sewer_n_17253464.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/laura-kenny-interview-ambition-after-pregnancy_n_17252498.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/boris-johnson-radio-4-eddie-mair-two-ronnies_n_17245044.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/grenfell-tower-homes-theresa-may_n_17246764.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/dup-pushover-deal_n_17253218.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/khan-remain-rights_n_17243656.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/love-island-zara-holland-sex-miss-great-britain_n_17242768.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/man-sent-home-from-work-wearing-shorts_n_17243276.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/courteney-cox-fillers-surgery-face_n_17252410.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/21/jeremy-corbyn-observed-protocol-by-not-bowing-to-the-queen_n_17240658.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/alexandra-shulman-british-vogue-good-morning-britain-the-queen_n_17253200.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/teaching-excellence-framework-results-universities-gold-ranking_n_17253426.html?utm_hp_ref=uk', 'http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2017/06/22/prince-harry-slams-decision-to-make-him-walk-behind-princess-dianas-coffin_n_17253188.html?utm_hp_ref=uk']
for url in urls:
    print url
    text = get_text(url)
```